# Is Proposition 2.6 in J. Silverman's book Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves correct?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, algebraic-curves

In J. Silverman's book "Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves" Chapter 2 Proposition 2.6 (a) it is considered a non constant morphism $\Phi:C_{1}→C_{2}$ between two smooth curves defined over a perfect field $K$.

I am having trouble understanding why there is no inertia degree appearing in the degree formula $\deg(\Phi)=\sum_{P\in \Phi^{-1}(Q)}e_{\Phi}(P)$ for any $Q\in C_{2}$. I don't see why in general the inertia degree should be 1 and not appear in the well known degree formula as it does in standard Number Theory.

This is what I mean: as the curves are smooth the regular functions rings are Dedekind domains and we have the unique factorization $M_{\Phi(P)}=\prod_{P′\in \Phi^{-1}(\Phi(P))}M_{P'}^{e_{\Phi}(P′)}$ being $M_{\Phi(P)}$ and $M_{P}$ the maximal ideals associated to $\Phi(P)$ and $P$ respectively (as $\Phi$ is non constant $\Phi^{*}$ is injective and embeds $K[C_{2}]$ in $K[C_{1}]$). In the degree formula the inertia degree should appear by standard Number Theory, which is not the case.

Comment: Why does "$K$ become algebraically closed" in characteristic $0$?

Comment: It doesn't sorry for the confusion, I have edited the question. I was thinking to something else

Comment: Just a reminder to accept the answer if it answered your question (if for nothing else than to keep the Unanswered tab unclogged)

Answer (score 15):

The reason is that there are two ways of thinking about "points".

Let $A$ be a ring. Then, define:

1. A scheme-theoretic/topological point of Spec $A$ is a prime ideal of $A$.
2. A geometric/functorial point of Spec $A$ is an equivalence class of morphisms Spec $K\rightarrow$ Spec $A$, where $K$ is a field, and two morphisms:
   $$p_1 : \text{Spec }K_1\rightarrow \text{Spec }A,\qquad p_2 : \text{Spec }K_2\rightarrow\text{Spec }A$$
   are equivalent if there exists a field $K$ containing both $K_1,K_2$ as subfields, and a morphism Spec $K\rightarrow$ Spec $A$ making the obvious diagrams commute.

Note that if $A$ is a $k$-algebra, then geometric points of Spec $A$ are just morphisms Spec $\overline{k}\rightarrow\text{Spec }A$. Further, if $A$ is a finite type $k$-algebra (for example $k[x,y]/(f)$) then a geometric point of $\text{Spec }k[x,y]/(f)$ is nothing but a pair $(a,b)\in\overline{k}^2$ satisfying the equation $f$, which is precisely how Silverman defines a "point".

Here's an example that will explain everything:

Let $k = \mathbb{Q}$, and let $A = \mathbb{Q}[x]$, $B = \mathbb{Q}[y]$, and suppose $X = \text{Spec }A$ and $Y = \text{Spec }B$. Consider the map $f : Y\rightarrow X$ given by $x\mapsto y^2$. This map is degree 2, and sends $y = a$ in $Y$ to $x = a^2$ in $X$.

First, lets consider the scheme-theoretic/topological point $q\in X$ corresponding to $x = -1$. Thus, $q$ is the prime ideal $(x+1)\subset\mathbb{Q}[x]$. It's not hard to check that the only prime of $B$ lying over $q$ is $p := (x^2+1)$, whose residue field is $\mathbb{Q}(i)$, so $p$ has "inertia degree" 2 over $q$.

Now, lets consider the geometric point $Q : $Spec $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}\rightarrow$ Spec $A$ given by sending $x\mapsto -1$. It's not hard to see that sending $y\mapsto i$ and sending $y\mapsto -i$ define two distinct morphisms $P_1,P_2 : \overline{\mathbb{Q}}\rightarrow$ Spec $B$ (ie, two distinct geometric points) which lie above $Q$.

Thus, while there is only one topological point above $x = -1$, there are two geometric points, each of which makes an appearance as a summand of the equation in Prop 2.6. This makes up for the fact that the inertia degree doesn't appear. In fact, one may *define* the inertia degree as the number of geometric points lying over $x = -1$ who have the same image $P\in Y$.

Ie, in the situation of our morphism $f : Y\rightarrow X$, the two equivalent ways of writing the formula would be:

1. $deg(f) = 2\cdot e_f(p) = 2\cdot 1$ (2 is the inertia degree), or
2. $deg(f) = e_f(P_1) + e_f(P_2) = 1 + 1$